# undefined behavior when strcat

Tags: c, strcat

```
in = "(A + B) * C - D * F + C";
#define MAXL 256
```

I'm having a problem with my code at `case ')'`.

My code is unfinished since it misses a few lines of code somewhere to add all the final `char = operators` inside stack to `tempExp` which I'll probably figure out soon™. What I need at the moment is your input with why this line `while(c[0] != '(') strcat(tempExp, c);` would result in undefined behavior.

Thank you very much!

Note: the reason for this messy code `c[0] = *((char*)pop(s))` is that pop returns a `void*` which I cannot change for the purpose of this exercise.

```
void convertIntoPost(char * in, char ** out)
{
    int i;
    Stack * s = createStack();
    char tempExp[MAXL] = "temp: ", c[2];
    c[1] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s\n", tempExp);
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(in); ++i)
    {
        printf("i: %d", i);
        c[0] = in[i];
        if(isalpha(c[0]) || isalnum(c[0]))
        {
            c[0] = in[i];
            printf("\nc passed isalpha OR isalnum: %s\n", c);
            strcat(tempExp, c);
        }
        else
        {
            switch(in[i])
            {
                case ' ' : break;
                case '(' :
                    push(s, &in[i]);
                    break;
                case ')' :
                    c[0] = *((char*)pop(s));
                    printf("c in case ')': %s", c); /* Show expected result */
                    printf("\n%s", tempExp); /* Just checking tempExp and see no problem */
                    while(c[0] != '(')
                        strcat(tempExp, c);
                    printf("\n%s", tempExp); /* Program stopped before it gets here */
                    break;
                default :
                    while(!isEmpty(s) && (priority(in[i]) <= priority(c[0] = *((char*)pop(s)))))
                        strcat(tempExp, c);
                    push(s, &in[i]);
            }               
        }            
    }
    printf("\nThis is in: %s", in);
    printf("\n%s", tempExp);
    *out = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempExp) + 1);
    *out = strdup(tempExp);
    makeEmpty(s);
}

int priority(char c)
{
    if(c == '(')
        return(0);
    else if(c == '+' || c == '-')
        return(1);
    else if(c == '*' || c == '/')
        return(2);
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to have the condition `i <= strlen(in)` in that loop? That will cause the loop to include the string terminator in `in`.

Comment: Either that while will never run, or it will never stop.

Comment: `strcat` (continuously) concatenates the entire string `c`, not just the first character. It also doesn't cut it off `c`. It seems you come from another language.

Comment: @Pawan why should he? At Mizushima: consider removing the *undefined behavior* tag.

Comment: @Joachim I tested, strlen return the length of string excluding the terminator. This is the 3rd pass of `in` from another function, 2 previous passes didn't crash the program.

Comment: @Pawan Have I misread the two line code you are suggesting to try? They seems to be equivalent to the OP code and still make no sense to me. How could this cycle `while(c[0] != "(") strcat(tempExp, c);` stop?

Comment: @knm21, Ah i overlooked while part, my bad. I was just concentrating on "strcat" part becasue of the title of this question. I agree. I deleted my earlier comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop

```
while(c[0] != '(')
   strcat(tempExp, c);
```

will run indefinitely (assuming c[0] is not '('), overrunning the size of your string (256 chars), as it will keep adding the same string (c) onto the tempExp.  This will cause a myriad of errors, but usually a stack overflow or buffer overflow ... Undefined behaviour only when the end of the string (256) is reached, from then on it will crash unelegantly

Comment: It's that simple! Thank you very much! I change while to if and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the infinite loop pointed out by Grantly, you also have several other problems, mostly because of two things:

1. Your loop includes the string terminator of `in`, so you will end up in the default case in the `switch` statement where you will call, in effect, `priority('\0')` which leads to your second problem. You will also call `push` with a pointer to the string terminator, and if `push` assumes that the pointer is not to the end of the string you might have problems there too.
2. The second problem is with the `priority` function, because it does not return a value for all branches leading to *undefined behavior* if you pass a character not expected in your conditions (like for example the string terminator). You need to add an explicit `else` clause.

Comment: In your first point, I have a high chance of being wrong here but when I test `strlen` statement: `char c = "123456789"; printf("%d", strlen(c));` would show 9 which is the length excluding the terminator so I fail to see how `'\0'` will get in my loop. Please help me see it. Your second point, I believe you're right and I'm working on it right now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MizushimaHideyoshi Remember that indexes goes from *zero*, so the correct indexes of the string `"123456789"` is `0` to `8` (inclusive).

Comment: Oh that's right! That's an elementary error. I'm sorry I was obtuse. Thank you for clearing it up!